# How to use two conditon in one array?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data

I have a list of task stored in Mongo, like below

```
{
"name": "task1",
"requiredOS": [
    {
        "name": "linux",
        "version": [
            "6.0"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "windows",
        "version": [
            "2008",
            "2008R2"
        ]
    }
],
"requiredSW": [
    {
        "name": "MySQL",
        "version": [
            "1.0"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

My purpose is to filter the task by OS and Software, for example the user give me below filter condition

```
{
"keyword": [
    {
        "OS": [
            {
                "name": "linux", 
                "version": [
                    "6.0"
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "name": "windows", 
                "version": [
                    "2008"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "SW": [ ]
    }
]
```

}

I need filter out all the task can both running on the windows2008 and Linux 6.0 by searching the "requiredOS" and "requiredSW" filed. As you seen, the search condition is an array (the "OS" part). I have a trouble when use an array as search condition. I expect the query to return me a list of Task which satisfy the condition.

A challenging thing is that I need to integrate the query in to spring-data using @Query. so the query must be parameterized

can anyone give me a hand ?

I have tried a query but return nothing. my purpose is to use $all to combine two condition together then use $elemMatch to search the "requiredOS" field

```
{"requiredOS":{"$elemMatch":{"$all":[{"name":"linux","version":"5.0"},{"name":"windows","version":"2008"}]}}}
```

Comment: I don't think you are clearly stating what it is that you expect to match, or even the result you expect. Your question could elaborate that you expect your "tested" query to return a certain result, and also show some data from which that result could be returned. Currently none of those conditions are true.

Comment: sorry for not stating clearing. Currently I have a number of "Task" stored in the Mongo, the json structure is shown in the first section of code. I want to match the "requiredOS" and "requiredSW" array field. the search condition is like the json in section 2. it is also any array( the "OS" part ). so I am not very clearly how to use an array as a search condition. Do I state clear now ?

Comment: Not really. As I said your "sample" cannot possibly match your conditions so that makes it hard for people to understand. I can guess at your "conditions" trying to match an empty array. But really your whole intent is not clear. Use the "edit" link on the question and clarify before commenting to people who showed an interest in helping. That is what comments are for, and "questions" are where you state your intent, not in comments.

Comment: I think his question is pretty clearly stated, when he says his `purpose is to filter the task by OS and Software`. It seems evident that he wants to `find` all documents that have some specified values mentioned in the query, in the `requiredOS` and `requiredSW` arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You basically seem to need to translate your "parameters" into a query form that produces results, rather than passing them straight though. Here is an example "translation" where the "empty" array is considered to match "anything".

Also the other conditions do not "literally" go straight through. The reason for this is that in that form MongoDB considers it to mean an "exact match". So what you want is a combination of the [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator for multiple array conditions, and the [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) operator which combines the conditions on the same property element.

This is a bit longer than [**`$all`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) but essentially because that operator is a "shortened" form of `$and` as [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) is to [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/):

```js
db.collection.find({
    "$and": [
        {
            "requiredOS": { 
                "$elemMatch": {
                    "name": "linux",
                    "version": "6.0"
                 }
            }
        },
        {
            "requiredOS": {
                "$elemMatch": {
                    "name": "windows",
                    "version": "2008"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

So it just a matter of transforming the properties in the request to actually match the required query form.

Building this into a query object can be done in a number of ways, such as using the Query builder:

```js
    DBObject query = new Query(
        new Criteria().andOperator(
            Criteria.where("requiredOS").elemMatch(
                Criteria.where("name").is("linux").and("version").is("6.0")
            ),
            Criteria.where("requiredOS").elemMatch(
                Criteria.where("name").is("windows").and("version").is("2008")
            )
        )
    ).getQueryObject();
```

Which you can then pass in to a mongoOperations method as a query object or any other method that accepts the query object.

Comment: I get your point. one last question. do you have know how to execute a json in java using mongoTemplate. the executeCommand() function can only run mongo command. the executeQuery() function can only run Query object

Comment: @XiranLi It's just a matter of constructing a query object with your criteria. This can be done using BasicDBObject or any available builder as shown.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you are trying, you need to use $elemMatch operator:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch

Taking your example, the query should be like:
@Query("{'requiredOS':{$elemMatch:{name:'linux', version:'7.0'},$elemMatch:{name:'windows', version:'2008'}}}")

It match the document you provided.

Comment: I think your code won't work, because if you use the same operator two times in the same query's document or subdocument, only the last operator's occurence is kept. In this case, your query would be equivalent to: `{requiredOS: {$elemMatch: {name: "windows", version: 2008}}}`

Comment: Yes, I have tested the query. it will indeed keep the last operator.